# error in inserting cell type numbers for fuzzy input

Tags: matlab, user-interface, fuzzy

I want to make a system content Fuzzy, so first I make the graphical system shape in GUI. The main sector of my system is a table that some columns of this table must be filled by user, other rows must be filled after Fuzzy processes. Then, I make the Fuzzy system separately, and when I want to insert cell type numbers (instead of Fuzzy input variables) to my Fuzzy system in MATLAB using command window, this error appeared:

```
"??? Undefined function or method 'min' for input arguments of type 'cell'."
```

Please help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably unrelated to your "Fuzzy" application.

From the error, you are either explicitly trying to `min()`over a cell array entries or passing `cell`input arguments to a function that expects `double.`

```
% example cell array of doubles (one per entry) 
N = 4; cellArray = mat2cell(randi(10, N, N), ones(N,1), ones(N,1));

% min of all
minCellArray = min([cellArray{:}]);

% min of two entries
minSubArray = min(cellArray{1}, cellArray{2});
```

Now compare the above with trying to do `minSubArray = min(cellArray(1), cellArray(2))`, which will generate the same error as the one you get.

Overall, beware of the `cellArray{i}` vs `cellArray(i)` assignment or passing (as input) to functions.

Comment: Thank you @gevang. Do you have any idea how to call my fuzzy system from the GUI, actually i want to get data from user,then input it the fuzzy, then reply the answer to the GUI.
Can you help me about this problem?

Comment: This is a very generic description and problem. You should probably break it up in smaller sub-problems and make a different posts about specific things you tried and did not work.